# Viewdata not showing in partial view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Hi guys i have controller which returns a partial view, the controller is called by ajax script. The partical view has no problem showing viewdata first time, But when ajax script is invoked second time the partical view does not update it self with new viewdata.

code for controller

```
   [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult getPart(int id)
    {
        ViewData["partical"] = id;

        return PartialView("test");
    }
```

code for partial view

```
 <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<PovertyBayHotel.Models.testmodel>" %>


 <p>just a test</p>

 <%: ViewData["partical"]%>
```

and the ajax which call the controller

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {

     $("#DropDown").change(function () {
         var course = $("#DropDown > option:selected").attr("value");
         $.ajax({
             type: 'GET',
             url: '/Reservation/getPart',
             data: { id: course },
             success: function (data) {

                 $('#ExtraBox').replaceWith(data);
             }
         });

     });
 });

</script>
```

Comment: might be a caching issue. Try HTTP POST instead of GET.

Comment: tried both it does not seem to work :(

Comment: tried to debug your code? Can you post the HTTP response (headers and etc.) you are getting?

Comment: I debugged by adding breakpoints, every time i call the ajax script the call landed in the controller getpart() with new value. But however the view returned shows the previous value.

Comment: can you look at the HTTP response? For example, on chrome by `CTRL + SHIFT + I` under the Network tab.

Comment: Yes! each time i click on the ajax code, the network shows post. here it is: 3 requests  ❘  912B transferred
getPart
/Reservation
POST
200
OK
text/html
jquery.js:142
Script
304B
45B
130ms
120ms
120ms10ms
getPart
/Reservation
POST
200
OK
text/html
jquery.js:142
Script
304B
45B
100ms
90ms
90ms10ms
getPart
/Reservation
POST
200
OK
text/html
jquery.js:142
Script
304B
45B
105ms
100ms
100ms5ms

Comment: can you put the solution up somewhere so that I can get it and have a look?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9637/discussion-between-jonny-and-tugberk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be a caching issue. Try HTTP POST instead of GET or set the `ifModified` and `cache` options to `false` as below:

```
 $("#DropDown").change(function () {
     var course = $("#DropDown > option:selected").attr("value");
     $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         ifModified: false,
         cache: false,
         url: '/Reservation/getPart',
         data: { id: course },
         success: function (data) {

             $('#ExtraBox').replaceWith(data);
         }
     });
```

Also, try to debug your code and see really what is going on.

**Edit:**

The problem has been solved by changing `$('#ExtraBox').replaceWith(data);` with `$('#ExtraBox').html(data);`.